# How can I get engagement data over time for an Instagram business account user and media post (IG Graph API)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, social-networking, instagram-graph-api, social-media

I would like to know if there is a way to get engagement for a month (ex. get total engagement from current date minus 30 days) for an Instagram post in the
[Instagram Media Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights) or total engagement from a month from [Instagram User Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights).

As of now from the IG Media Insights, it seems you can only get cumulative engagement (see snippet below taken from [IG Media Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights):

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "impressions",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 264
        }
      ],
      "title": "Impressions",
      "description": "Total number of times the media object has been seen",
      "id": "17855590849148465/insights/impressions/lifetime"
    },
    {
      "name": "reach",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 103
        }
      ],
      "title": "Reach",
      "description": "Total number of unique accounts that have seen the media object",
      "id": "17855590849148465/insights/reach/lifetime"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you for your time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IG Media Insights you can only see lifetime metrics. If you wanted a monthly breakdown you would have to build a mechanism to query the lifetimes every month and calculate the delta to track monthly change.

For IG Account Insights you can use metrics which offer `days_28` period or use the `since` and `until` filtering.

Comment: Hi Andrew! Thank you for your reply. Some follow-up questions:

1. What mechanism to query data would you recommend to get lifetimes every month?

2. What do you mean by delta to track monthly change?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: At the end of every month call the Media Insights API and store the lifetime metrics values, subtract last month value from the current month and the difference would be the change over the last month

Comment: Ok thank you for your advice! Have a great day!